# Grave accent in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some directive in angular which can be called

```
<div some-directive parameter='{"option":"value"}'>...</div>
```

i need to use this directive in another directive template. I'm trying to use the grave accent

```
template:
'<div some-directive parameter=`{"region":"33"}`> ... < /div>',
```

but i got

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ̀
```

How can i call another directive with parameters? I tried using \' or more " but it doesn't work. I also can't change directive which i'm trying to call.

Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grave accent should not be used. Instead, escape the second occurrence of `'` with `\'`:

```
template: '<div some-directive parameter="{region: \'33\'}">...</div>',
```